# full-text and knn_vector hybrid search for elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, embedding, hybrid

I am currently working on a search engine and i've started to implement semantic search. I use open distro version of elastic and my mapping look like this for the moment :

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "knn": true,
      "knn.space_type": "cosinesimil"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": { 
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "data": { 
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "title_embeddings": {
        "type": "knn_vector", 
        "dimension": 600
      },
      "data_embeddings": {
        "type": "knn_vector", 
        "dimension": 600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for basic knn_vector search i use this :

```
{
  "size": size,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": { }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field1]) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field2])",
        "params": {
          "field1": "title_embeddings",
          "field2": "data_embeddings",
          "query_value": query_vec
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i've managed to get a, kind of, hybrid search with this :

```
{
  "size": size,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": { 
          "query": query,
          "fields": ["data", "title"]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field1]) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field2])",
          "params": {
            "field1": "title_embeddings",
            "field2": "data_embeddings",
            "query_value": query_vec
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that if i don't have the word in the document, then it is not returned. For example, with the first search query, when  i search for trump (which is not in my dataset) i manage to get document about social network and politic. I don't have these results with the hybrid search.

I have tried this :

```
 {
  "size": size,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": { }
      },
      "functions": [
      {
        "filter" : {
          "multi_match": { 
            "query": query,
            "fields": ["data", "title"]
          }
        },
        "weight": 1
      },
      {
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field1]) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field2])",
            "params": {
              "field1": "title_embeddings",
              "field2": "data_embeddings",
              "query_value": query_vec
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": 4
      }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

but the multi match part give a constant score to all documents that match and i want to use the filter to rank my document like in normal full text query. Any idea to do it ? Or should i use another strategy? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can just put the multi_match in the query section where you have match_all. replace the match_all with your multi_match.
Filters are for filtering (they don't provide a relevance score like you noted. The query section is the one you need for scoring

Comment: I did that on the first hybrid search, the problem is that i don't have the result of the example with trump. I want to have the ability to weigth how much i want text scoring and vector scoring.

Comment: for example if i have no full text result, that i would be able to match embedding query.

Comment: i would like a scoring function that score exactly like the multi_match query but that could be used like the script_score

Comment: okay, i skimmed through the question. try using `query.bool.should.multi_match`. If that still doesn't work. Then try with some param like minimum_should_match (you can google). I think you can pass something like 0 or 0% to that param. But try with just `should` block first, it might work without minimum_should_match

Comment: Not sure about the last part: "i would like a scoring function that score exactly like the multi_match query but that could be used like the script_score". With bool.should (working right) you can get matches with no occurrences of your keywords, having the score from your script. But if there are matches, then mult_match will assign a tf/idf (or bm25 etc) score to the results, after which the score can be modified by your script (using params like `score_mode` or `boost_mode`)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When i am using query.bool.shoul.multi_match query with minimum_should_match at 0, it give me the same as if i would have use query.multi_match (so the same result as i have in my first hybrid search). I understand what you want me to do but i can't find a way to match 0 percent of my query

Comment: okay maybe try: query.bool.should[0].match_all:{}
query.bool.should[1].multi_match.
Sorry i don't have ES setup with me right now or i could have checked. Also been some time so im not updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, with some tricks i have managed to find how to do, I'll put it in my post, if someone search for the same thing +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the help of Archit Saxena here is the solution of my problems :

```
{
  "size": size,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": { 
          "should" : [
            {
              "multi_match" : { 
                "query": query,
                "fields": ["data", "title"]
              }
            },
            {
              "match_all": { }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match" : 0
        }
      },
      "functions": [
      {
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field1]) + cosineSimilarity(params.query_value, doc[params.field2])",
            "params": {
              "field1": "title_embeddings",
              "field2": "data_embeddings",
              "query_value": query_vec
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": 20
      }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this use approximate nearest neighbor search or does an exhaustive search?